# f having a zero of order N implies f(z)/z^N has a removable singularity.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove this simple result: $f$ holomorphic on the unit disc with a zero of order $N$ at $0$. Show $f(z)/z^N$ has a removable singularity at $0$.

I am trying to apply Riemann continuation theorem, but I don't see how to show that $\lim_{z\to 0} z f(z)/z^N = \lim_{z\to 0} f(z)/z^{N-1} = 0$.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Write $f(z)=\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n z^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying that $f$ has a zero of order $N$ at $0$ means that
$$
f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=\dots=f^{(N-1)}(0)=0
$$
and that $f^{(N)}(0)\ne0$. Thus the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$ is
$$
f(z)=\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}z^k=
z^N\sum_{k=0}\frac{f^{(k-N)}(0)}{(k+N)!}z^k
$$

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!